# React bootstrap table edit modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using react-bootstrap-table in my webapp to show data in tables. Everything is working fine. I wonder tho, is there a way to use the "insert modal" as "edit modal". If I want to add a new row, I will just tell create table with

```
<BootstrapTable data={ this.props.data } insertRow={ true } ..>columns...
```

and "New" button appears and I can insert a new row to my table. If I want to edit some values in my row, I can enable cell editing which makes my cell become editable when doubleClicking it. But can I somehow use the "insert modal" for editing too, where my column values are already filled? I added an edit button to each row where I can access the row properties.